# Не подключается общая папка в гостевой ОС Убунту на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

На Виндоус 7 стоит Виртуалбокс с гостевой ос Убунту 18.04. В настройках виртуалбокс прописан общий путь до общей папки в виндоус(чекбоксы постоянная папка и автоподключение выставлены). В гостевой ос установлены Дополнения гостевой ос и даже переустановлены. Убунту была перезагружена несколько раз. Но гостевая папка так и не появляется в системе в папке медиа или других папках. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: `mount` чё показывает?

Answer (score 1):

У вас нету прав на эту папку. Выполните данную команду, где вместо < user > установите вашего пользователя, для которого надо предоставить права. После этого перезапустите систему.

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf <user>
```

Comment: я эту команду делала. у меня не появлялась папка из винды в убунту

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился установкой новой версии Виртуалбокс 6.0. После обновления виртуалбокс в убунту появилась папка из виндоус.